# CSS автоматический сдвиг влево

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: у меня контент автоматически не выравнивается влево, объяснить трудно, лучше скрин приложу: (левая картинка - это главная картинка, а вот то что идет после текста должно автоматически выравниваться влево, т.е становится под картинку)

[image: СКРИН 1]

---

А еще, если в категории нет контента, то линия футера лезет прямо на категории:

[image: СКРИН 2]

Comment: Дайте ссылку, где можно посмотреть сие чудо инженерии?
Тут были ребята с хорошо прокачаной телепатией, но все таки, если показать код - больше шансов, что помогут

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
<div id="это_первый_блок" style="float:left;width:ширина_">...</div>
<div id="это_второй_блок" style="float:left;width:ширина">...</div>
<div id="это_после_них" style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В случае с картинками: посмотрите на CSS директивы для картинки... Скорее всего там стоти выравнивание вправо...
По поводу футера: проверяйте состояние, если нет контента то вставляйте пустой слой определенной величины...
Почитайте документацию по CSS, относительно  позиционирования элементов.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить `width:auto;`